# Generate an auto increment number in select query increase by 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to generate auto increment number in a select query but increase by 2. so it should look like following

```
Column1       Column2         Sequence
some Value    some Value      2
some Value    some Value      4
some Value    some Value      6
```

I tried `ROW_NUMBER` but didn't find any option to increase the number by 2. I'm using **PostgreSQL**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * , row_number() over () * 2
from table;
```

Comment: @Jazz00 you are welcome , please upvote  and accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Can't upvote yet since its a new account, but did for the record and accepted the correct answer. Thanks again for the help!